# How to prevent listBox_SelectedIndexChanged event when DataSource is bound?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have ListBox control(WinForm project).

When I bind DataSource to the ListBox control  listBox_SelectedIndexChanged event is fired.

Here is the code:

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        string conn ="consntring";

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Colors", conn);

        DSColors dataSetcColors = new DSColors();

        adapter.Fill(dataSetcColors.Colors); 


        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ColorName";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ColorID";
        listBox1.DataSource = dataSetcColors.Colors;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Any idea how to prevent listBox_SelectedIndexChanged event when DataSource is bound?

Comment: where are you binding the listbox? show some code

Comment: You can't prevent the event from firing. You _can_ simply not implement an event handler, or an empty one.

Comment: Is there any another handler that I should use?

Comment: duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905447/how-to-prevent-listbox-selectedindexchanged-event  , I recommend : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10099694/992406